# Generate coordinate points with circle pattern points in Octave

Tags: matlab, random, octave

[image: Two types of samples with circle pattern]

I want to generate 300 samples of both types, red and blue, of coordinate points with these patterns.
Using rand() for x and then calculate y using Pythagorean theorem doesn't help because for the same x, we can have different y.

Comment: I suggest generaring in polar coordinates, then converting to Cartesian if needed. Anyway, your question is unclear. You should include your attempted code. Also, the circles are not properly specified. For example, what thickness should the red one have?

Comment: Thank for comment. But that's all I get for the answer as well. I can't give you more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Luis Mendo, you can use the typical `rand` function of matlab to generate random points in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) as follows:

```
figure
hold on

red = sampleCircle([1.4 1.6], 300);
plot(red(:, 1), red(:, 2), 'r*');

blue = sampleCircle([0 0.5], 300);
plot(blue(:, 1), blue(:, 2), 'b*');

function X = sampleCircle(rangeR, n)
  r = rand(n, 1) * diff(rangeR) + rangeR(1);
  theta = rand(n, 1) * 2*pi;

  X = r .* [cos(theta) sin(theta)];
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, never think of polar coordinates. As the question state no further, I see that you assume the width of the circle and uniformly random number between those range, however seeing some outlier in blue class, I was thinking about random generate based on some distribution function that I don't know of. I wonder if this exercise can be solved with some distribution function.

Comment: You keep mentioning an exercise or answers as if this is a problem that you have been given. You can't expect us to provide an answer to your satisfaction when you have not relayed the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Try to use another random generator in Matlab. You should be able to find one using your favorite search engine.